# Why glimpse ignores failed requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

Some ajax request or full get requests results in HTTP error. I can not see those failed requests Ajax and History tabs on Glimpse. I am expecting to see those requests. Is this expected behavior ? If not what can be problem about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Glimpse only responds to certain status codes (200, maybe a few others). If you want to have it respond to errors or some of the typical REST responses (201, 202, 204, etc), you'll have to whitelist them in your `web.config`...

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <runtimePolicies>
      <statusCodes>
        <add statusCode="201"/>
        <add statusCode="404"/>
        <add statusCode="500"/>
      </statusCodes>
    </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

There's a small bit in the docs that talks about this...
http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration